# openpyxl insert a value into cell ValueError: Cannot convert array([nan]) to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a dataframe:

```
final_1.head()
  symbol    System suggested long   System suggested short
0 USDJPY    - 1.500000              NaN
1 EURUSD     NaN                    NaN
2 NZDJPY     0.622222               NaN
3 USDCHF     -9.222222              NaN
4 AXC/AUD    0.533438               NaN
```

I have one excel:

```
  A         B                      C
1 symbol    System suggested long  System suggested short
2 AUDUSD
3 EURUSD
4 USDJPY
```

So I need to insert the dataframe to the excel, only one part of symbols of the excel are in the dataframe: so I wrote the code:

```
for rowNum in range(2,sheet.max_row):
    symbol = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
    if symbol in final_1['symbol'].values:
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value = final_1.loc[final_1['symbol']==symbol]['System suggested long'].values
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=5).value = final_1.loc[final_1['symbol']==symbol]['System suggested short'].values
```

```
Then I got the error:
ValueError: Cannot convert array([nan]) to Excel
```

The question is I need to insert the value NaN to the excel; I assume other may have the same problem, so I post it here, many thanks

Comment: if value is nan then you could add str(nan) before writing

Comment: good point! let me have a try

Comment: thank you very much! this works! what a clever person you are